# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not read class: VirtualFile: Kotlin+ Apache Beam defined runner

Tags: kotlin, apache-beam

I implemented an example using Kotlin + Apache Beam to define the Kotlin properties of the pipes but when I ran the project I got the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not read class: VirtualFile: /Users/duanybaro/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.beam/beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java/2.27.0/3e551e54b23441cc58c9d01e6614ff67216a7e87/beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java-2.27.0.jar!/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowPipelineJob.class
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.classFiles.BinaryJavaClass.<init>(BinaryJavaClass.kt:122)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.classFiles.BinaryJavaClass.<init>(BinaryJavaClass.kt:34)
```

[image]

This error only occurs in Kotlin because, with the code made in java, it works perfectly. Can you give me any suggestions to solve the error?

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend you using the [latest](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/downloads/) version of `Apache Beam`, your version is very old.

You can also use the [starter](https://beam.apache.org/blog/beam-starter-projects/) for `Beam` `Kotlin`.

I share with your an example of `Kotlin` `Beam` project from my `Github` [repo](https://github.com/tosun-si/teams-league-kotlin-dlq-asgarde-beam-summit) based on `Maven`.

For the `Beam` pipeline options, can you try with instead of using `DataflowPipelineOptions` :

```kotlin
val options = PipelineOptionsFactory
        .fromArgs(*args)
        .withValidation()
        .`as`(TeamLeagueOptions::class.java)

val pipeline = Pipeline.create(options)
```

Example of PipelineOptions :

```kotlin
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Description
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions

interface TeamLeagueOptions : PipelineOptions {
    @get:Description("Path of the input Json file to read from")
    var inputJsonFile: String

    @get:Description("Path of the slogans file to read from")
    var inputFileSlogans: String

    @get:Description("Path of the file to write to")
    var teamLeagueDataset: String

    @get:Description("Team stats table")
    var teamStatsTable: String

    @get:Description("Job type")
    var jobType: String

    @get:Description("Failure output dataset")
    var failureOutputDataset: String

    @get:Description("Failure output table")
    var failureOutputTable: String

    @get:Description("Feature name for failures")
    var failureFeatureName: String
}
```

And pass program argument in the mvn command line :

```bash
mvn compile exec:java \
  -Dexec.mainClass=fr.groupbees.application.TeamLeagueApp \
  -Dexec.args=" \
  --project=my-project \
  --runner=DataflowRunner \
  --jobName=team-league-kotlin-job-$(date +'%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S') \
  --region=europe-west1 \
  --streaming=false \
  --zone=europe-west1-d \
  --tempLocation=gs://mazlum_dev/dataflow/temp \
  --gcpTempLocation=gs://mazlum_dev/dataflow/temp \
  --stagingLocation=gs://mazlum_dev/dataflow/staging \
  --inputJsonFile=gs://mazlum_dev/team_league/input/json/input_teams_stats_raw.json \
  --inputFileSlogans=gs://mazlum_dev/team_league/input/json/input_team_slogans.json \
  --teamLeagueDataset=mazlum_test \
  --teamStatsTable=team_stat \
  --jobType=team_league_kotlin_ingestion_job \
  --failureOutputDataset=mazlum_test \
  --failureOutputTable=job_failure \
  --failureFeatureName=team_league \
  " \
  -Pdataflow-runner
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I downgrade the version, trying to resolve the issue but this change didn't solve it.  Currently, I using version 2.44.0 but I have the same issue. The funny thing is that with java it works correctly. 
Do you have any other idea of what can be the problem?

Comment: Have you checked the project in my Github repository ?
Are you using Maven ?

Comment: Yes, I reviewed it and also put my code using the starter for Beam Kotlin and I have the same issue.

Comment: I updated my answer with another way of using Beam Pipeline options with `Dataflow`, can you try it please ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Mazlum. I was able to successfully run the pipeline using the command 
"./gradlew run -Dpipeline="pocBigqueryMongoDbDuany" --args="--runner=DataflowRunner" --stacktrace
"
This was the only way I found but I think it's something.

Comment: You're welcome, if my answer helped you, can you upvote and mark it as solved please ?